# Cross-contract calls in Aeternity

Tags: blockchain, aeternity-blockchain

I'm checking on Sophia documentation (https://aeternity-sophia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts/#calling-other-contracts) but I don't get how can I perform cross-contract calls from one Sophia contract to another Sophia contract(call another contract functions from one Sophia contract). Do I have to create an interface or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

For making a contract call from another contract you need to:

1. Create an interface on the caller contract with the entry points of your interest of the to-be-called contract (ie MyRemoteContract):

> ```
> contract MyRemoteContract =
>   entrypoint my_remote_entrypoint : (int) => bool
>   entrypoint another_remote_entrypoint : (address, int) => bool
> ```

2. Manage the other contract inside your caller contract (ie: keeping it in your state)

> ```
> contract MyCallerContract = 
>   record state = {
>     some_field : address,
>     remote_contract_instance : MyRemoteContract }
> ```

3. Finally when you are doing your init you can send by parameter your remote contract address to instantiate on your caller contract

> ```
> stateful entrypoint init( remote_contract_instance_param : MyRemoteContract) : state = {
>   remote_contract_instance = remote_contract_instance_param }
> ```

4. When calling to this contract (caller) you will need to tell him the address (ct_....) of the instance of the deployed contract
5. From now own your contract will be able to call any remote entrypoint you got on the interface.

> ```
> stateful entrypoint try_remote_call(value: int) =
>   state.token.my_remote_entrypoint(value)
> ```

Some side note, be careful when your remote contract does **Call.caller** uses because it won't be the actual address but the contract address as caller.

Answer (score -1):

To call another contract, you can deploy the first contract and then pass the same parameter into the method for the call